# How to Make System Settings Lists Alphabetical

Tags: gnome, 20.04, system-settings, gnome-tweaks

When I open up `System Settings` in Ubuntu 20.04 the settings are not listed alphabetically. They are listed in this exact order:

#### System Settings

```
WiFi
Network
Bluetooth
Background
Appearance
Search
Applications
Privacy
Online Accounts
Sharing
...
a dozen more entries
...
```

How can I sort this list alphabetical? It is very slow trying to hunt and peck non-alphabetical lists.

---

**Bonus** - Maybe this should be a second separate question but it's so similar, here goes... the Gnome Tweak Tool (settings) suffers the same fate. Can this Tweak Tool list be alphabetical?

#### Gnome Tweak Tool Settings

```
General
Appearance
Extensions
Fonts
Keyboard Mouse
Startup Apps
Top Bar
Window Titlebars
Windows
Workspaces
```

Comment: I think the only way is to recompile `gnome-control-center` after editing your preferences..